# Bounding the expectation of a product of random variables using Hölder's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, holder-inequality

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$ be centered random variables which are not necessarily independent.  Under what conditions do we have a bound of the form $$\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_1 X_2 \cdots X_k \right\rvert \leq C \sqrt{(\mathbb{E} X_1^2)(\mathbb{E} X_2^2) \cdots (\mathbb{E} X_k^2)}$$ for some constant $C > 0$?

- When $k \leq 2$, this follows from Hölder's inequality: $$\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_1 X_2 \right\rvert \leq \sqrt{(\mathbb{E} X_1^2) (\mathbb{E} X_2^2)}.$$  However, for general $k$, Hölder only gives $$\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_1 X_2 \cdots X_k \right\rvert \leq \sqrt[k]{(\mathbb{E} X_1^k) (\mathbb{E} X_2^k) \cdots (\mathbb{E} X_k^k)},$$ and in general we do not have $\sqrt[k]{\mathbb{E} X_i^k} \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E} X_i^2}$.
- This also holds if $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$ are independent.  In that case, we have $$\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_1 X_2 \cdots X_k \right\rvert = (\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_1 \right\rvert) (\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_2 \right\rvert) \cdots (\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X_k \right\rvert) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E} X_1^2} \sqrt{\mathbb{E} X_2^2} \cdots \sqrt{\mathbb{E} X_k^2}$$
- But it cannot hold in general. Suppose $X_1 = X_2 = \cdots = X_k = X$.  Then this inequality says $\mathbb{E} \left\lvert X^k \right\rvert \leq C (\mathbb{E} X^2)^{k/2}$, which would imply that if a random variable $X$ has finite second moments, then it has moments of all orders.  This is false: consider a real-valued random variable with probability density function proportional to $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$, for instance.
- The random variable $X$ in the counterexample in the previous bullet point is unbounded.  What if we assumed that $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$ were bounded?

---

**Motivation**

I'm trying to follow an argument in [Bryc, Dembo, and Jiang, "Spectral measure of large random Hankel, Markov and Toeplitz matrices."](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307330)  Near the end of their proof of Proposition 4.12 (page 30 of the arXiv version), they have $$f_n(w) = \sum_{i=1}^q \mathbb{E}\left[ L_w (Q_{a_i} - \tilde{Q}_{a_i}) \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} M_{a_j, a_j} \prod_{j=i+1}^q \tilde{M}_{a_j, a_j} \right],$$ and they write "since the distribution of $(L_w, \{Q_i\}, \{\tilde{Q}_i\})$ is independent of $n > 2k$, while $M_{ii}$ and $\tilde{M}_{ii}$ are normal of mean zero and variance at most $n + 2$, it follows by Hölder's inequality that $\left\vert f_n(w) \right\rvert \leq C_w n^{(q(w) - 1) / 2}$..."

My real question is how this conclusion can be obtained.  I can see that based on the information provided, the outer summation and the terms with $L_w$, $Q_i$, or $\tilde{Q}_i$ do not depend on $n$ and can be absorbed into the constant $C_w$.  So it remains to study $\mathbb{E}(\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} M_{a_j, a_j} \prod_{j=i+1}^q \tilde{M}_{a_j, a_j})$, which is the expectation of a product of $q-1$ factors. If the inequality at the top of this post holds, then we would have $$\mathbb{E}(\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} M_{a_j, a_j} \prod_{j=i+1}^q \tilde{M}_{a_j, a_j}) \leq \sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} \mathbb{E} M_{a_j, a_j}^2 \prod_{j=i+1}^q \mathbb{E}\tilde{M}_{a_j, a_j}^2}.$$ Using $\mathbb{E}M_{a_j, a_j}^2 = O(n)$ and $\mathbb{E}\tilde{M}_{a_j, a_j}^2 = O(n)$, we deduce that the whole expression is $O(n^{(q-1)/2})$, as claimed.  However, I'm not seeing the Hölder's inequality argument that would establish the last inequality.

Comment: There is a Holder inequality for products of $n$ random variables.

Comment: @Mason Yes, but it seems that it is insufficient to prove the result that I want (see the first bullet point).  Is there a clever way of applying the inequality that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this question? Would be interested, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have no idea.